# Check mobile device is configured with email account using jquery,html5 and asp.net mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html

Can anyone guide me with sample code regarding how to check whether mobile device is configured or has a setup with a email account. I am using jquery and html5,asp.net mvc3 for the mobile devices development.

I want to check whether the mobile device is configured with email account or not .If not force user to first setup his mail account and then try to send mail.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to detect whether an email account is configured on a device using the technologies you listed.

On certain platforms, API functionality may exist to enable you to do this via a 'native' application.  For example, if you're developing with Google Android, you could use getAccountsByType in com.google as the account type to see if the user has any Google accounts.

I hope this answers your question.